# Double Summation with double index

Tags: summation

I have that question:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} a_{i,j}
$$
I try to understand how to sum this double summation works, so I try to sum it up to 3,
but so far managed to find 3 different solutions.
$$
1.(a_{1,2}+a_{1,2}+a_{2,3})
$$$$
2.(a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{2,1}+a_{2,3})
$$$$
3.(a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{2,3}+a_{3,3})
$$

I think that the first could be the right one but im not sure.
which one of them is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=i+1}^{3} a_{i,j} = \left( \sum_{j=2}^3 a_{1,j}\right) + \left( \sum_{j=3}^3 a_{2,j}\right) + \left( \sum_{j=4}^3 a_{3,j}\right) = a_{1,2} + a_{1,3} + a_{2,3} $$

so none of your options are correct.